# How to launch both native app and chrome browser on android to switch between them

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I am facing a problem, I want to test Browser links on a native app, when I clicked on links from the native app then the browser is opened but from the browser, I want to check whether this link is matched with my expected result below is my code can anyone to figure out the problem

1) this is my case in this test case I have opened the desired screen and click on the facebook link when I clicked on facebook link facebook is opened in the browser, from the browser I want to get the actual URL

Below is my code

```
@Test(priority = 10)//Validate that FaceBook Link is working Fine 
    public void ValidateFacebookLink() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        WebElement FaceBookLinkID = driver
                .findElement(By.id("com.fittingnzidd.cherripik.development:id/tv_share_biz_fb"));
        FaceBookLinkID.click();
      //  CherryPikLaunchInBrowser();
        chromeBrowser();


    }

    public void chromeBrowser() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Set <String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
        for (String contextName : contextNames) {
            System.out.println("WebView:"+contextName);
        if (contextName.contains("WEBVIEW")){
        driver.context(contextName); 
        System.out.println("WebView:"+contextName);
        String ActualURL=driver.getCurrentUrl();
        }
        //driver.context("NATIVE");
    }

    }
```